# Is it possible to create a switch group in Netlogo?

Tags: design-patterns, netlogo

Sorry if this question is weird, I'm still switching over my programming brain from OOP.

### Problem

I have a collection of switches. And I want to create the same amount of patch colors as switches that are currently on.

### How I would solve it

For example in python I would use the following code to get the number of switches with value `1`:

```
sum(switch_hashmap.values())
```

## Question

So my question stems from my neophyte approach to solving this problem. By thinking of switches as an object that has elementary functions built into it. I'm avoiding writing a dozen `if blocks` as that smells like bad design.

Is this possible in netlogo? What is the best practice here?

Comment: There is only one `breed` for `patches`. Do you mean attributes? Perhaps this would be easier if you gave some examples of what these switches operate. In NetLogo, a `switch` sets a variable (usually global) to true or false. But it's not clear that this is what you mean.

Comment: I just realized that I coded patch 'breeds' as simply different colors. I will fix my question to correctly communicate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have switches `a`, `b` and `c` on you interface tab. To get the number of switches that are currently on, you can simply do:

```
sum (map [ v -> ifelse-value v [ 1 ] [ 0 ] ] (list a b c))
```

The `(list a b c)` part uses the state of your switches to build a list of booleans, which we then `map` to a list of ones and zeros that we can sum. Except for the non-object-orientedness and the fact that you have to explicitly convert booleans to 1 or 0, it's not *that* far from your Python code.

Still, I don't believe that "thinking of switches as an object that has elementary functions built into it" is the right conceptual framework. It is true that interface widgets are internally represented as objects, but from the point of view of a NetLogo programmer, they should just be thought of as a bunch of global variables that happen to be modifiable by the user.